# My bluetooth earbuds aren't working?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I'm using BCM20702A0 as my Bluetooth transmitter for my earbuds and i'm using Nmotion BTHL-201 for my earbuds.

Sound is being transmitted but the only problem is that the left side seems to be a lot louder than the right, I still get sound outputted from both ear buds.

All drivers are up to date, it didn't use to be like this, at the beginning both sides were both equally loud. When I go to the earbuds to see if everything is balanced out correctly (both sides are at 100) they are so I'm not quite sure what's wrong?

Comment: Did you test your ear plugs with another device (another smartphone or computer)? By doing this, you could find out if it is the ear plugs or the device that plays the music. Maybe one of the ear plugs is damaged (cables in it broken or similar)?

Comment: Bluetooth transmits both sides of stereo in the same channel, so its either software on the computer or one of the audio drivers (hardware not software) in the earbuds is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem with cheapo 99 cents story earbuds. This is a hardware failure and not a driver problem. I would recommend doing the following:
1. Test it on other devices to see if this is a software-based issue (though I doubt it ), or boot windows in safe mode and see if the problem persists. 
2. Put one side higher than the other until you can get a refund.

According to the manufacturer, if the earbuds are less than 1 yr old, then you can 'file a warrant' to get a refund or new pair.

If you could give us a bit more background info on when this happened than we could help you more. When did this happen? What caused it to do this?

Comment: Yea, I uninstalled and re-installed the bluetooth software and it fixed it

Comment: and nothing had really caused it, it just kind of happened